# In what file are flags, set in Google Chrome, being saved?

Tags: google-chrome

When running Chrome Beta Portable and changing a flag in `chrome://flags`, where (in which file) is the status of this flag being saved?

I tried running a program monitoring all the files in the Chrome Portable directory but it was next to impossible to determine which of the changes belonged to the newly set flag.

Answer (score 17):

They are stored in the `Browser` block of the the plain-text file `Local State`, which is located in the [User Data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

For example, the file

```
%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State
```

Would contain something like:

```
{
  …
  "browser": {
    "enabled_labs_experiments": [ "disable-gpu-vsync", "extension-apis", … ],
    …
  }
  …
}
```

Comment: Please, use well-known environmant variables instead of hardcoded user-specific paths
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\
This will work in all applications

Comment: [Chrome OS](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/u8u0uu/wheres_the_preference_file/i5nizu4)